# Inputs can be answered, no printing occurs but still gives exit code 0

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm brand spanks new to Python, I'm really enjoying but I'm running into an issue.

I'm trying to use some of the basics of python to understand what I'm writing, so apologies if the syntax or grammar of my code is terrible.
Inputs sex and age can be answered but the code doesn't print the statements no matter what condition has been met.

I want the user to type male or female and for the printed output to be bruh or gurrl

```
male = "bruh"
female = "gurrl"

sex = input("Are you male or female: ")
age = int(input("how old are you: "))

while sex == male:
    if age >= 50:
        print("Damn, you are old as fudge, " + male)
        break
    elif age <= 49 >= 18:
        print("You're a spritely young " + male)
        break
    elif age < 18:
        print("Has your voice even dropped yet???")
        break

while sex == female:
    if age >= 50:
        print("you are old " + female)
        break
    elif age <= 49 >= 18:
        print("You're spritely young " + female)
        break
    elif age < 18:
        print("Has your voice even dropped yet???")
        break

#ammeded coded starts below this line
male = "bruh"
female = "gurrl"

sex = input("Are you male or female: ")
age = int(input("how old are you: "))

while sex == "male":
    if age >= 50:
        print("Damn, you are old as fudge, " + male)
        break
    elif age >= 18 <= 49:
        print("You're a spritely young " + male)
        break
    elif age < 18:
        print(f"Has your voice even dropped yet{male}???")
        break

while sex == "female":
    if age >= 50:
        print("you are old " + female)
        break
    elif age >= 18 <= 49:
        print("You're spritely young " + female)
    elif age < 18:
        print(f"Has your voice even dropped yet {female}???")
        break
'''

If there is a prettier way for my code to be written could you explain why you would do it differently please?

Also please do not take printed statements to heart, its just gibberish I promise XD

I have tried taking the breaks out it still gives me exit code 0 with no printed statements.
I Have tried using for loops but it comes up with far more errors within my code that I don't have the necessary knowledge to debug

I'm expecting a printed statement when I meet certain conditions of the while loop.
```

Comment: What _exactly_ did you try to enter as input? Because you said "*I want the user to type male or female*", if the input is "male", then that would never satisfy your `while` loop conditions because "male" != "bruh". On that matter, if `sex` is never updated inside the loop, then your `while` should just be regular `if`.

Comment: @GinoMempin so I added quotation marks around male and female in both while loops. and it gave me what I want but then the last conditions of the while loops were not being met. I didn't realise that numerical order matters in an IF statement. Code added to main code

Comment: `age >= 18 <= 49:` is invalid. Use the more verbose `age >=18 and age <= 49`.